# switching 1 phase 230Vrms with a relay

Tags: relay

I have a 230Vrms 1 phase output and i need to switch this with another circuit with a relay.
The relays are all given in ...VAC.

Is VAC= VRMS or do i need to take a relay with 330VAC(Vrms*sqrt(2))?

Comment: Assume all AC voltage ratings are in RMS unless otherwise stated in electric engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, whenever we talk about AC, we really mean the RMS value.

This came from the DC-AC switchover (after Edison lost the war of the currents). There was a huge installed base of 110VDC light bulbs.  "110" V AC was chosen to be the voltage at which those light bulbs would be happy, i.e. produce the same amount of net power, thermal rise, light, and therefore not burn out prematurely.  It would be bad press for AC if light bulbs were dimmer or burned out prematurely.

You know with resistive loads, power (watts) is proportional to voltage squared. As the math works out, the difference is the square root of 2.

But anything rated in AC should be accounting for this, yes.  If you find a relay that is *only* rated in DC, you might need to deal with that. But I doubt anyone would ever *fail* to rate a relay for AC, because AC voltage is much easier to interrupt (since it crosses zero frequently).

**Here's the thing.  If you see an AC relay, don't multiply its AC rating by 1.414 and say "Oh, it can interrupt that high a DC voltage".  *It really can't*.  It does not ever cross zero, and so nothing snuffs a DC arc**.  DC voltage above about 50V is a very different animal. It does not know pity or remorse or fear and [it absolutely will not stop, ever,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThIbMnE71HU) until all conductive paths are utterly consumed. (wait until 2:30 in this video for the second round of mad arcing, and that's only 600V).  Relays rely heavily on this characteristic of AC, and typical relay DC ratings are 1/4 to 1/10 the voltage of their AC rating.

I saw a circa-1995 design on a light rail vehicle. For a 600VDC main contactor, they chose a Siemens 960VAC 3-phase contactor, and wired all 3 phases *in series*.  Even this was off-label; the manufacturer did not approve.

Answer (score 2):

Unless otherwise specified, yes, VAC is assumed to be the RMS value.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is VAC= VRMS*

If the relay is sourced from a reputable supplier or sourced from a reputable manufacturer and it has a proper believable data sheet then the default values for AC voltages and currents is RMS.

[Wikipedia quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude#Root_mean_square_amplitude)

[image]